# Can't understand Delphi XE6 protected types

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

I create two units and put a first class into one of them:

```
  unit UBaseClass;

  interface

  type
    TBaseOuterClass = class
    protected type

      TBaseInnerClass = class
      public
      end;

    protected
      function GetInnerInstance: TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass; virtual;
    end;

  implementation

  { TBaseOuterClass }

  function TBaseOuterClass.GetInnerInstance: TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass;
  begin
  // doesn't matter
  end;

  end.
```

And I put a derived class into a second unit:

```
unit UDerClass;

interface

uses
  UBaseClass;

type
  TDerOuterClass = class(TBaseOuterClass)
  protected type

    TDerInnerClass = class(TBaseInnerClass)

    end;

  protected
    function GetInnerInstance: TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TDerOuterClass }

function TDerOuterClass.GetInnerInstance: TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass;
begin

end;

end.
```

When I'm trying to compile I get

> [dcc32 Error] UDerClass.pas(22): E2362 Cannot access protected symbol
>   TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass

at the line function TDerOuterClass.GetInnerInstance: TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass;

I can't understand why TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass (as inner protected class) isn't accessible from TDerOuterClass (which is derived for TBaseOuterClass). What in this case are protected types actually for?

I haven't found any explanation for this at [Nested Type Declarations topic](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE6/en/Nested_Type_Declarations). So are there any reasons for this behaviour?

It's also relevant to simple protected types like

```
protected type    
  TSimpleType = Integer;
```

I can't write a function in TDerOuterClass

```
protected    
  function GetValue: TSimpleType;
```

since I'll get a message

> [dcc32 Error] UDerClass.pas(16): E2003 Undeclared identifier:
>   'TSimpleType'

Comment: Your example and analysis are very clear. This appears to be a defect. Submit a bug report to Quality Portal.

Comment: Fixed in 10.2 Tokyo: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16305

Answer (score 12):

It looks like a bug. I would suggest to post it to the [quality portal](http://quality.embarcadero.com/).

For now you could declare type alias to cheat the compiler (tested in XE7).

```
unit UDerClass;

interface

uses
  UBaseClass;

type
  TDerOuterClass = class(TBaseOuterClass)
  protected type
    TBaseInnerClass = TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass; // <= type alias to avoid compiler error

    TDerInnerClass = class(TBaseInnerClass)

    end;

  protected
    function GetInnerInstance: TBaseInnerClass; override;
  end;

implementation

{ TDerOuterClass }

function TDerOuterClass.GetInnerInstance: TBaseInnerClass;
begin
  Result := TDerInnerClass.Create;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work in Delphi XE6. Says [dcc32 Error] UDerClass.pas(45): E2362 Cannot access protected symbol TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass at the line function TDerOuterClass.GetInnerInstance: TBaseOuterClass.TBaseInnerClass;

Comment: Read your comment, read the answer. Notice that the code in your comment is different from the code in the answer. Use the code in the answer.

Comment: Is anybody going to submit a bug report?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've added [one](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16305)

Comment: Thank you very much